# How can the closure of $\frac{1}{n}$ have empty interior?

Tags: general-topology

I'm misunderstanding something despite reading the definition and the Wikipedia page. So as I see it, the interior is the set without its boundary. So how can the closure of $\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}$ with $0$, have an empty interior? Don't you just remove the $0$ and that's how you get the interior?

Comment: @AhmedHussein that should be the same, because of the interior is the union of every open subset, so for sure we have $A=A\cap \overline{A}= A\cap ( A^\circ \cup \partial A)= (A\cap A^\circ )\cup (A\cap  \partial A)$ hence $A\setminus \partial A= (A\cap A^\circ ) \setminus \partial A= A^\circ$ as the boundary and the interior are disjoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ does have an empty interior, because of every point of the set is in its boundary. If you put a small ball around any of its element some irrational number will be in it and hence something of the complement of your set.

Comment: So the definition assumes that the set is a "sea" of points. To me it's a bit confusing calling it the interior since the elements in 1/n are still "inside" its closure. The Wikipedia page says __the interior of a subset S of points of a topological space X consists of all points of S that do not belong to the boundary of S__ while further down it also says __If S is a subset of a Euclidean space, then x is an interior point of S if there exists an open ball centered at x which is completely contained in S.__ which I think contradict themselves, what do you think?

Comment: Oh I don't see a contradiction there. Not every point of the set is in the interior, interior means that there is a small neighbourhood that is completely in your set, and a point is in the boundary if in every neighbourhood there are points of your sets and points of the complement

Comment: Hmm ok but 0 is clearly the boundary since you can get as close to it as you want. So shouldn't the first definition just include all of 1/n?

Comment: @Gudumundur no the boundary of your set is $\{\frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$ so yes 0 is in the boundary but there is much more in the boundary

Comment: But can you approach any 1/n from  within 1/n? I believe the only number you can approach with 1/n is 0.

Comment: @gudmundur yeah $\{0\}$ is the only accumulation point, you are already at all those $\frac{1}{n}$ you can't come nearer

Comment: Re Gudmunder's second last comment:Being a limit point of a sequence of other points in the set does not, by itself, imply that it is in the boundary. It must also be in the closure of the complement.